# Incorrect "Can't rebase immutable changeset" error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Occasionally, when I do a pull with rebase, I get the following error:

```
abort: can't rebase immutable changeset fa044e766d1f
hint: see hg help phases for details
```

Funny thing is, that changeset that errors (and it is the same one every time) is very old, and is already public.

Here's a screenshot:https://db.tt/xHiOxm6R

It appears that I can just ignore the message (at least, so far, I've not gotten into any trouble by doing so), but obviously, I'd like to help Hg resolve this issue so that its not going to continue to be a hassle in the future.

Thanks.

### Update

hg out does not list it.  The clone is probably about 6 months old.  Also, as far as I know, none of the other developers are experiencing this problem.

Comment: If that changeset is already widespread, it might be better to just merge it instead.

Comment: I don't understand this.  The code was merged 3 years ago.  Merging shouldn't even be possible...

Comment: if you hg out to that repo you are pull --rebase from, does the ancient changeset show up in your list of changes to go out ? And do you ever get that error on recent clones of that repo ?

Comment: hg out does not list it.  The clone is probably about 6 months old.  Also, as far as I know, none of the other developers are experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 6):

*(note: I can't see the screenshot due to a strict firewall).*

You mention that the error occurs every time on a changeset that "is very old, and is already public."  This should give you a hint as to why you're getting the error.

Changesets in Mercurial have 3 possible phases:

```
 - public : changeset is visible on a public server
 - draft : changeset is not yet published
 - secret : changeset should not be pushed, pulled, or cloned
```

Changesets that are at `draft` and `secret` are considered to be mutable, that is you can change their history, modify them (perhaps change the author, for example), and so on.

Changesets that are at `public` are considered immutable, you "cannot" change anything about them when they are in this phase.  The reason being, they have already been seen by the outside world, and so if you make any modifications, it could cause issues.  The theory is that you can't remove a changeset that's public - if you tried to change it, you would simply create another changeset.

That said, you can force the phase of a changeset back to `draft` like so:

```
hg phase -d -f <changeset_id>
```

This would allow you to rebase, or modify the changeset in some other way.

**However**, this would *not* remove the original changeset in the "outside world"... that already exists, and will until the end of time itself.  It would simply create a new one that does mostly the same thing.

So, if you *did* try to resolve the issue, you would likely just create a new issue in its place.

*Caveat:* as I can't see the screenshot from here, I may revise my answer later.

**Update**: A quick note - having seen the screenshot, that looks like a *very* old changeset, which makes me wonder just what you're trying to rebase.  As Kindread mentions above, merging would be your best bet here.

Comment: I see...though this still makes no sense to me... it doesn't LOOK mergable, and honestly, I'm terrified of the impact such an even might have on the rest of my code...

Comment: as to what I am rebasing, its nothing more than current work.  As a curiosity, the files from that 'errant' changeset don't even exist in current versions of the software.  We re-wrote that code (transitioned away from flex/flash so we could get iPad support built in)